# Sails app crash when not calling skipper upload

Tags: sails.js, sails-skipper

If I call `req.file('files')` and not calling `updload` (for example because I throw validation error) the app crashes.

```js
const files = req.file('files')
if (!files || files.length === 0) {
  throw "MISSING_ARGUMENTS"; // intentally fails here
}
file.upload() // not reaching here
```

error :

```js
events.js:173
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EMAXBUFFER: An Upstream (`NOOP_files`) timed out before it was plugged into a receiver. It was still unused after waiting 4500ms. You can configure this timeout by changing the `maxTimeToBuffer` option.
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (../node_modules/sails/node_modules/skipper/standalone/Upstream/Upstream.js:86:15)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:327:15)
    at processTimers (timers.js:271:5)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Upstream.fatalIncomingError (../node_modules/sails/node_modules/skipper/standalone/Upstream/prototype.fatalIncomingError.js:95:8)
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (../node_modules/sails/node_modules/skipper/standalone/Upstream/Upstream.js:93:12)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:327:15)
    at processTimers (timers.js:271:5)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
Error: EMAXBUFFER: An Upstream (`NOOP_files`) timed out before it was plugged into a receiver. It was still unused after waiting 4500ms. You can configure this timeout by changing the `maxTimeToBuffer` option.
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (../node_modules/sails/node_modules/skipper/standalone/Upstream/Upstream.js:86:15)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:327:15)
    at processTimers (timers.js:271:5)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Upstream.fatalIncomingError (../node_modules/sails/node_modules/skipper/standalone/Upstream/prototype.fatalIncomingError.js:95:8)
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (../node_modules/sails/node_modules/skipper/standalone/Upstream/Upstream.js:93:12)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:327:15)
    at processTimers (timers.js:271:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue, in my case, I checked with `allParams()` that will prevent app from crashing.

```js
const fileDetials = !('image' in req.allParams()) ? req.file('fieldName') : '';
```

Comment: replace image with your fieldName